# Can anybody give me some much less formal words or expressions in oral English which have the meaning as "sybarite" and "epicurean"?

Tags: word-request

I need some less formal words for "sybarite" and "epicurean". They are hard to be find in dictionaries. 
(I consulted a thesaurus and found the word "epicurean" for "sybarite". I need some informal equivalents for them, which may not appear in a dictionary or thesaurus)
I don't need words like "voluptuary", "epicure"...

Comment: Use a thesaurus: [1](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/epicurean) [2](http://thesaurus.com/browse/sybarite) [3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/epicurean) [4](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/sybarite)

Comment: I think your best bet might be _hedonist_, although _sensualist_ might work better. I think this question may have had a shot at staying open had you (1) given a more precise context where you want to use the word, and (2) listed some of the synonyms that you found when you consulted your thesaurus. _"Here's my context – I'm trying to figure out which one of these synonyms sounds most 'normal' in everyday conversation"_ is a perfectly valid ELL question; but _"please give me some synonyms for this word"_ is likely to collect some close votes, as is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean "epicurean" in the sense of "person devoted to pleasure and comfort" rather than "follower of the philosophical teachings of Epicurus".

Assuming that, "hedonist" is a fairly common word. "Lush" is possible though decidedly insulting. Most common would probably be "pleasure-seeking person".